# Moving all non-clustered indexes to another filegroup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing, filegroup

In SQL Server 2008, I want to move ALL non-clustered indexes in a DB to a secondary filegroup. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: May I ask why you think you need this? There are a lot of myths around this.

Comment: I want to move the non-clustered indexes to a separate disk drive for performance benefits. I know doing this does create benefit. I worked with a top-level Caché developer, who introduced me to the concept.

Comment: @IanC: would be interested to hear back from you when you've done this to see if you can notice any performance benefits! Was contemplating this myself for a while

Comment: @marc_s Right now the DB is empty, so I won't have a "before & after" - but the logic of it is quite obvious: 2+ disks sharing the I/O.

Comment: @IanC: yes, agreed - in *theory*, there's no difference between theory and practice; in *practice* however,. .....

Comment: @marc of course. What I have settled on is to put the central super-busy and high-expanding table and its indexes on a secondary filegroup. That was a quick modification and one I'm sure will connect theory to practice :)

Comment: @IanC: some notes: are you sacrificing a large RAID 10 arrays to have an extra disk? Same disk controller (same cache and bandwidth now shared across 2 disks)? DB can fit in RAM (lot less disk IO)? Write speed is determined by log files disks etc etc. You really have to have extreme size and/or volumes: we don't bother with 10 million new rows per day because of what I just noted..

Comment: @gbn you make valid points, although if the cache was shared over 2 disks, what's the difference? It's till the same DB overall. Put it this way. I now have 3 files (1 mdf, 1 log, 1 mdn). They can all sit on the same disk for now. *If* the opportunity/need arises to move any files to separate disks, I can do so without having to rebuild parts of the DB. I still get the simplicity of using one RAID in the mean time. Of course, talking of RAID, if there were 2 controllers, we would have double the cache to use. So the way I see it, either way I win.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run this [updated script](https://gist.github.com/dalenewman/6377911) to create a stored procedure called `MoveIndexToFileGroup`.   This procedure moves all the non-clustered indexes on a table to a specified file group.  It even supports the `INCLUDE` columns that some other scripts do not.  In addition, it will not rebuild or move an index that is already on the desired file group.  Once you've created the procedure, call it like this:

```
EXEC MoveIndexToFileGroup @DBName = '<your database name>',
                          @SchemaName = '<schema name that defaults to dbo>',
                          @ObjectNameList = '<a table or list of tables>',
                          @IndexName = '<an index or NULL for all of them>',
                          @FileGroupName = '<the target file group>';
```

To create a script that will run this for each table in your database, switch your query output to text, and run this:

```
SELECT 'EXEC MoveIndexToFileGroup '''
    +TABLE_CATALOG+''','''
    +TABLE_SCHEMA+''','''
    +TABLE_NAME+''',NULL,''the target file group'';'
    +char(13)+char(10)
    +'GO'+char(13)+char(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

Please refer to the original [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramoji/archive/2008/09/26/how-to-move-existing-indexes-from-one-filegroup-to-another.aspx) for more details.  I did not write this procedure, but updated it according to the blog's responses and confirmed it works on both SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

#### Updates

1. @psteffek [modified the script](https://gist.github.com/psteffek/6877012) to work on SQL Server 2012. I merged his changes.
2. The procedure fails when your table has the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option on. No fix for this yet.
3. @srutzky pointed out the procedure does not guarantee to preserve the order of an index and made suggestions on how to fix it.  I updated the procedure accordingly.
4. [ojiNY](https://github.com/ojiNY) noted the procedure left out index filters (for compatibility with SQL 2005). Per his suggestion, I added them back in.

Answer (score 6):

Script them, change the ON clause, drop them, re-run the new script. There is no alternative really.

Luckily, there are scripts on the Interwebs such as this [one](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code951-how-to-move-nonclustered-indexes-from-one-filegroup-to-another-filegroup-w-.aspx) that will deal with scripting for you.

Comment: You could also use the `WITH DROP_EXISTING` clause on a new `CREATE INDEX` statement - saves you one step (the explicit DROP INDEX)

Answer (score 1):

Update: This thing will take long time to do step 2 manually if you are using MS SQL Server manager 2008R2 or earlier. I used sql server manager 2014, so it works well (because the way it export the drop and create index is easy to modify)
<strike>I tried to run script in SQL server 2014 and got some issue, I'm too lazy to detect the problems, SO I come up with another solution that not depend on the version of SQL server you are running.</strike>

1. Export your index (with drop and create)
   [image: Right click on your DB select Generate Scripts]

[image: Select Table you want to move the index]
[image]

2.Update your script, remove all things related to drop create tables, keep the thing belong to indexs. and Replace your original index with the new index (in my case, I replace ON [PRIMARY] by ON [SECONDARY]
[[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEG8J.png)

3. Run script! And wait until it done.

(You may want to save the script to run in some others environment).