# Moving all Clustered indexes to another Filegroup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-design, sql-server-2016, filegroup

In SQL Server 2016, I want to move ALL Clustered indexes in a DB to a secondary filegroup. What's the easiest way to do this?

This question is only for Nonclustered Indexes.

[Moving all non-clustered indexes to another filegroup in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237238/moving-all-non-clustered-indexes-to-another-filegroup-in-sql-server)

Note: Want to retain Nonclustered indexes in same filegroup, and prevent creating additional unique indexes on primary key

In the process of optimizing an older legacy database

Comment: Why not generating the drop/create script for all indexes and alter the script and drop/create all indexes?

Comment: Try this solution: [moving-large-number-of-tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16708/moving-large-number-of-tables-to-different-filegroups)

Comment: If you move a tables clustered index to a different filegroup. It just moves the table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/move-an-existing-index-to-a-different-filegroup?view=sql-server-2017#BeforeYouBegin.